How to get ID of MAX value?
I'm new to Excel and its VBA object model.
I have this table (A-D) sorted by A & B. For each A-B group of rows, I want to find the MAX D (Cost) value, and C (Sale-ID) of this max value. Like the smaller table (F1:J4). I mucked around with a pivot table, but can't get the Sale-ID. [Ignore the formatting, added for ease of reading]
In any case I'm looking for a VBA solution. I'm sure that I could make work it, if I created a Range for each A-B group. But how? The closest thing I could find was this question: GroupBy and Sum rows using multiple columns in Excel, but that doesn't give me the ID value, and seems rather unelegent.
Any pointers?


As an alternative; this ADO/SQL code produces a simple table on "Sheet1" without using any loops.
Sub Test()
    Dim objConn As Object, RS As Object, strSQL As String, strArgs As String, j As Integer

    Sheets("Sheet1").Range("M2:P" & Rows.Count).ClearContents
    
    Set objConn = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")

    strArgs = "Driver={Microsoft Excel Driver (*.xls, *.xlsx, *.xlsm, *.xlsb)}; Readonly=False; DBQ=" & ThisWorkbook.FullName
    
    objConn.Open strArgs

    strSQL = " Select T1.[Name], T1.[Product], T1.[Sale ID], T1.[Cost] From [Sheet1$] As T1 " & _
             " Left Join [Sheet1$] As T2 " & _
             " On (T1.[Name]= T2.[Name] And T1.[Product]= T2.[Product] And T2.[Cost] > T1.[Cost]) Where T2.[Name] Is Null " & _
             " Order By T1.[Name], T1.[Product]"
        
    Set RS = objConn.Execute(strSQL)
    
    Sheets("Sheet1").Range("M1:P1") = Array("Name", "Product", "Sale ID", "Cost")

    Sheets("Sheet1").Range("M2").CopyFromRecordset RS

    objConn.Close
    Set objConn = Nothing
End Sub



WOW. A bit much of an overkill no?
Well I guess it depends on the size of the table. Would that work even if the file had unsaved changes? I haven't looked at DB connections in  LONG time.

I KNOW that SQL can nicely get the ID from the join. I'm just a bit surprised that Excel-VBA doesn't enable this natively.

It's not an overkill but rather a professional approach in data analysis
